# Join to Pivot Table Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am making a search with multiple inputs and consults to a database, my form is simple this is the structure of my POST

```
[search-word] => casas
[status] => sale,rent
[type] => condo,house,commercial,lot,fractional,business,boat,villa
[beds] => 2
[baths] => 3
[amenities] => handicap facilities,children allowed,security,furnished,pet friendly,jacuzzy
```

After i obtain and make the querys in this way

```
$query = "SELECT pr.* FROM properties as pr 
  INNER JOIN status as st
    ON pr.status_id = st.id
  INNER JOIN types as ty
    ON pr.type_id = ty.id
  INNER JOIN property_has_features as prfe
    ON prfe.property_id = pr.id
  INNER JOIN features as fe
    ON prfe.feature_id = fe.id
  WHERE ";
```

The Status and the Type has a foreign key in the properties table with status_id and type_id but the amenities is a pivot table properties_has_features i am trying to obtain that with the last two joins

```
INNER JOIN property_has_features as prfe
ON prfe.property_id = pr.id
INNER JOIN features as fe
ON prfe.feature_id = fe.id
```

But this not work, after all i fetch the arrays for get the values

```
$status = explode(",", $status);
$type = explode(",", $type);
$amenities = explode(",", $amenities);
$statusCount = 0;
$typeCount = 0;
$amenitiesCount = 0;

foreach ($status as $v) {
  if ($statusCount > 0){
    $query .= "OR ";
  }
  $query .= "st.title = '$v' "; 
  ++$statusCount;
}

foreach ($type as $k) {
  if ($typeCount > 0){
    $query .= "OR ";
  }else{
    $query .= "AND ";
  }
  $query .= "ty.title = '$k' "; 
  ++$typeCount;
}

foreach ($amenities as $j) {
  if ($amenitiesCount > 0){
    $query .= "OR ";
  }else{
    $query .= "AND ";
  }
  $query .= "fe.title = '$j' "; 
  ++$amenitiesCount;
}

$query .= "
  AND pr.beds LIKE '%".$beds."' 
  AND pr.baths LIKE '%".$baths."'
";
```

Whit this i get all the properties but not filtered for the amenities, if i remove the amenities of the query this work fine with type and status, i was looking and view some about Group_concat() and other things but i want suggest about my problem, thanks

UPDATE

This is the actual query what i get from that consult

```
SELECT pr.* FROM properties as pr 
  INNER JOIN status as st
    ON pr.status_id = st.id
  INNER JOIN types as ty
    ON pr.type_id = ty.id
  INNER JOIN property_has_features as prfe
    ON prfe.property_id = pr.id
  INNER JOIN features as fe
    ON prfe.feature_id = fe.id
  WHERE st.title = 'sale' OR st.title = 'rent' AND ty.title = 'condo' OR ty.title = 'house' OR ty.title = 'commercial' OR ty.title = 'lot' OR ty.title = 'fractional' OR ty.title = 'business' OR ty.title = 'boat' OR ty.title = 'villa' AND fe.title = 'handicap facilities' OR fe.title = 'children allowed' OR fe.title = 'security' OR fe.title = 'furnished' OR fe.title = 'pet friendly' OR fe.title = 'jacuzzy' 
AND pr.beds LIKE '%' 
AND pr.baths LIKE '%'
```

UPDATE:

I need to obtain this

```
[id] => 172
[permalink] => https://sample.com/properties-for-sale/villa-1-tres-mares
[title] => Villa 1 Tres Mares
[description] => Beautiful and spacious oceanfront villa at the exclusive Tres Mares Development. This fully furnished 5 bedroom and 7 bathroom unit is ideal for families and the large terraces and balconies provide outstanding views of the bay, yachts and cruises. Its’ unique location at the Tres Mares Development allows access to upscale amenities such as a private beach, infinity pool, spa and health club, tennis courts, concierge service and poolside restaurant. Ready to move in, Villa 1 Tres Mares is the ultimate modern and luxurious Marina living experience.
[images] => {"image0":"https:\/\/sample.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/01\/whatsapp-image-2018-01-17-at-13-58-37-1-250x120.jpeg","image1":"https:\/\/sample.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/01\/whatsapp-image-2018-01-17-at-13-58-29-11-250x120.jpeg","image2":"https:\/\/sample.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/01\/whatsapp-image-2018-01-17-at-13-58-26-1-250x120.jpeg"}
[position] => {"lat":"20.6565743795159","lng":"-105.24673819541931"}
[price] => 1750000
[baths] => 7
[beds] => 5
[parking] => 2
[lang] => en
[property_id] => 6640
[status_id] => 1
[location_id] => 11
[type_id] => 11
[created_at] => 2018-01-24 18:08:58
[updated_at] => 2018-01-24 18:08:58
```

This is pivot table properties_has_features

```
id | property_id | featured_id
```

The features table has

```
id | title
```

[image]

Comment: Do the results need to match _all_ selected amenities or just at least one?

Comment: I need at least one, i update the answer for show the actual query i obtain

Comment: Assuming that's the case for all of the selections, then really none of this is working as you expect.  You need to enclose each group within parenthesis.  Also, you should check if each array is empty before looping through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// I'm largely leaving your code as-is, but you could replace the
// list of ORs with an IN()
// The main change is that you need to enclose each attribute group
// within parenthesis so that the logical AND/OR processing is correct
if(is_array($status) && !empty($status))
{
    foreach ($status as $v) {
        if ($statusCount > 0){
            $query .= "OR ";
        }
        else{
            $query .= "(";
        }
        $query .= "st.title = '$v' "; 
        ++$statusCount;
    }

    $query .= ")";
}

if(is_array($type) && !empty($type))
{
    foreach ($type as $k) {
        if ($typeCount > 0){
            $query .= "OR ";
        }else{
            $query .= "AND (";
        }
        $query .= "ty.title = '$k' "; 
        ++$typeCount;
    }

    $query .= ")";
}

if(is_array($amenities) && !empty($amenities))
{
    foreach ($amenities as $j) {
        if ($amenitiesCount > 0){
            $query .= "OR ";
        }else{
            $query .= "AND (";
        }
        $query .= "fe.title = '$j' "; 
        ++$amenitiesCount;
    }

    $query .= ")";
}

// I'm not sure about the logic here, but I don't know what the data
// in your pr.beds and pr.baths columns looks like. I would think
// you'd want some sort of greater-than-equal comparison here or something
$query .= "
  AND pr.beds LIKE '%".$beds."' 
  AND pr.baths LIKE '%".$baths."'
";
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dMVUHtMh1gSiUWewkGShmT/0)

Comment: Ok ok i got it, i know more now jajajaj, the beds and baths are only numbers 2  and 3 something like that, not working yet but i think is good way to make to work, i think the problem is in the Joins of the Pivot tables really, i dont knwo if i am making good in thant

Comment: The joins should be fine (although, if you were posting IDs instead of titles, you wouldn't need most of your joins at all).  Did you try what I posted?

Comment: yes i already try, for example implement your code and search Bar i get this query 
      `WHERE (st.title = 'sale' OR st.title = 'rent' ) AND (ty.title = 'condo' OR ty.title = 'house' OR ty.title = 'commercial' OR ty.title = 'lot' OR ty.title = 'fractional' OR ty.title = 'business' OR ty.title = 'boat' OR ty.title = 'villa' ) AND (fe.title = 'bar' )` and i know i have a properties with amenitie bar and i get No Results

Comment: Put sample data in your question and also the expected results.

Comment: I already the field i want from properties, that not have amenities because the table amenities is pivot table

Comment: I can't help you any further if you don't provide sample table data that corresponds to your expected results.

Comment: I add a image from the database is that what you need? regards

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct table names. You have used different names to refer to the same tables in multiple spots in your question. Also, check that your data is really what you think it is.  See [THIS EXAMPLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dMVUHtMh1gSiUWewkGShmT/0) showing that the query works and produces the expected match.

Comment: I feel so stupid :v, all work fine only the id of amenitie bar what i was making the test not was the id correct and obviously never give me properties but i try with other amenitie and work fine, thanks you code help me very much :D

Comment: Glad I could help